# Doctrine won't persist modified data

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

So I am trying to persist an entity in Doctrine. The object I am looking to persist looks like this pulled from the Symfony dump() function:

```
Time {#7751 ▼
  -id: 3
  -timeIn: DateTime {#7749 ▶}
  -timeOut: null
  -rateId: Rate {#7761 ▼
    -id: 1
    -amount: "30.00"
    -name: "Technical"
    -projectId: Project {#7756 ▶}
    -groupId: 1
  }
  -description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  -userId: 1
  -status: "Unpaid"
  -total: null
  -cost: "60.00"
  -projectId: Project {#7756 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "Acme Corp"
    -description: "Metals Company"
    -contactId: 1
    -organizationId: 1
    -groupId: 1
  }
  -groupId: 1
  }
```

Now I obviously cannot persist this because I have the corresponding objects in their Ids. Ex: rateId, projectId, etc. So to compensate for this, in my clockOut function, I run a check to replace the objects with their IDs for storage. See clockOut function below:

```
public function clockOut($time, $group = null){
    dump($time);
    if(gettype($time) == "object"){
        if(gettype($time->getProjectId())=='object'){
            $time->setProjectId($time->getProjectId()->getId());
        }
        if(gettype($time->getRateId())=='object'){
            $time->setRateId($time->getRateId()->getId());
        }
        $this->persistClockout($time);
    }
    elseif(gettype($time) == "string"){
        if($group == null){
            return false;
        }else {
            $time = $this->findData($group, $time);
            $this->persistClockout($time);
        }
    }else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There is also a corresponding persistClockout function that handles the actual clocking out and hour calculation. Although I don't think this really has anything to do with the issue I'm having I'm going to include it anyway because it's related.

```
/**
 * Persist time
 */
private function persistClockout($time, $group = null){
    if($time->getTimeOut() == null){
        $time->setTimeOut(new DateTime("Now"));
    }
    $this->hours = $this->hoursCalculate($time->getTimeIn(), $time->getTimeOut());
    $time->setTotal($this->hours);
    dump($time);
    die();
    $this->persist($time);
}

/**
 * Get the amount of hours spent in decimal format.
 */
private function hoursCalculate($past, $present){
    $diff = $present->diff($past);
    $hours = round($diff->s / 3600 + $diff->i / 60 + $diff->h + $diff->days * 24, 2);
    return $hours;
}
```

Now as you can see I run the dump() function right before the end of the command before it persists because I've been trying to diagnose this issue myself. According to the dump() function the data looks like this:

```
Time {#7751 ▼
  -id: 3
  -timeIn: DateTime {#7749 ▶}
  -timeOut: DateTime {#11571 ▶}
  -rateId: 1
  -description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  -userId: 1
  -status: "Unpaid"
  -total: 187.83
  -cost: "60.00"
  -projectId: 1
  -groupId: 1
}
```

Great! That's the expected result. But the problem comes when I start trying to do the actual persisting to the database.

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE rate SET project_id = ? WHERE id = ? AND group_id = ?' with params [{}, 1, 1]:

Notice: Object of class ProjectBundle\Entity\Project could not be converted to int
```

While I checked the data right before I ran the persist function, it seems to still think projectId is still an object, even though I made sure to set it to the actual Id and not the object, it ignores me.

I went further and looked into the Symfony profiler and found the portion that doctrine uses to update and viewed the details, lo and behold projectId is an object? Even though that wasn't what I passed in?

[image: Symfony Profiler SQL update with params listed.]

Anyone have nay idea what's going on? Sorry for the wordy post, I just wanted to give you guys some information of what you're working with. Please ignore the dump() and die() functions in the code, I've been using those to try and diagnose this but I'm puzzled. It's worth noting I've tried the run of the mill stuff like php bin/console cache:clear, and restarting the server.

Thank you ahead of time stack overflow!

**EDIT:**

Below is the code listed for ->persist()

```
    public function persist($entity, bool $flush = true)
{
    $this->manager->persist($entity);

    if ($flush) {
        $this->flush();
    }

    return $this;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I tried running persist and then flush separately but that didn't work. Got the same exception. I'm honestly at a loss here guys.

Comment: Could you post one of your entities with the mapping? All the work you do with mapping object's to their identifier looks wrong to me. This is exactly what Doctrine will do for you under the hood. You should not need to resolve anything. The error looks like Doctrine tries to resolve how to get the id from the related object, but because their is an int instead of an object it will fail.

Comment: There seems to be a conflict between your `UPDATE` query and entity structure. Your `Time` clearly stores ids (and not references to `Project` or `Rate`) but for some reason you pass `Project` to you query. Do you? Can you post the `persist($time)` function?

Comment: Added the persist function from my base manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 
It turns out that it was an issue with how doctrine identifies different pieces of data and what it considers to be the same. I would assume that this has something to do with efficiency or caching or something along those lines.

Anyways, let me tell you how I came to this conclusion.

The first hint that I had was that while rateId was an object initially, and later was converted into it's corresponding ID, it did not throw an error like ProjectId did.

Secondly, I examined the dump() function much closer and noticed something. (I'll reuse the example from my original post)

```
Time {#7751 ▼
  -id: 3
  -timeIn: DateTime {#7749 ▶}
  -timeOut: null
  -rateId: Rate {#7761 ▼
    -id: 1
    -amount: "30.00"
    -name: "Technical"
    -projectId: Project {#7756 ▶}  <---- Right Here
    -groupId: 1
  }
  -description: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
  -userId: 1
  -status: "Unpaid"
  -total: null
  -cost: "60.00"
  -projectId: Project {#7756 ▼  <---- Right Here
    -id: 1
    -name: "Acme Corp"
    -description: "Metals Company"
    -contactId: 1
    -organizationId: 1
    -groupId: 1
  }
  -groupId: 1
  }
```

The numbers after the Project objects were the same. So I came up with a theory that doctrine was storing the original reference to projectId (object) somewhere and using that instead of the value I went on to set later as the corresponding ID (Int).

So to test this theory I wrote two functions to "Flatten" my object starting from the end of the tree of objects (Since it really should only go up to 3 nested objects) to the beginning. That way all of the references matched up even though they were eventually "deleted".

```
 /**
 * Undo all object associations and convert them back into their original IDs. 
 * @param object $data
 * @param array $callable
 */
public function flattenObject($data, $callable){
    $sorter = new SortingHelper;
    foreach($callable as $call){
        $getMethod = 'get'.ucfirst($call).'Id';
        $setMethod = 'set'.ucfirst($call).'Id';
        if(method_exists($data, $getMethod)){
            $found = $data->$getMethod();
            if(gettype($found) == 'object'){
                $result = $this->flatten($found, $callable);
                $data->$setMethod($result);
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}

/**
 * @param object $data 
 * @param array $callable
 */
private function flatten($data, $callable){
    for($i = 0; $i != count($callable); $i++){
        $getMethod = 'get'.ucfirst($callable[$i]).'Id';
        $setMethod = 'set'.ucfirst($callable[$i]).'Id';
        if(method_exists($data, $getMethod)){
            $result = $data->$getMethod();
            if(gettype($result) == 'object'){
                $data->$setMethod($result->getId());
            }
        }
    }
    return $data->getId();
}
```

Running the flattenObject() function allowed for me to persist the object into the database because the references to the IDs were no longer objects.

Bam. Super annoying problem solved.

I hope this somehow helps someone in the future. Thank you everyone who contributed! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you needed to use this code:

```
$this->flush($time);
```

instead of `$this->persist($time);`

Comment: Edited my post to include the persist function which runs flush within it.